# How can I create a file into run function of thread in php?

Tags: php

If I use `fopen()` outside of run method it's working but it is not working in run method,

```
 <?php
    class Test extends Thread{
       public function run(){
            $h = fopen("xyz.txt", "w+");
            fclose($h);
        }
    }
    $p = new Test();
            $p->start();
            $p->join();

     ?>
```

I want to create `xyz.txt` file on call of `start();` function.

Comment: There is no `start()` function. You can use [`touch()`](http://php.net/touch) to create the file... `function start() { touch("xyz.txt"); }`

Comment: I create file in constructor itself.my problem solved. Thanks ! Ryan

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special about fopen inside a thread using pthreads.so . Here is an example:

```
<?php

$test = new Test();

class Test
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        // A test folder
        $folder = "/home/jkon/www/test";

        // If you like to interact in other ways you could keep that as
        // private property
        $thread = new TestThread($this, $folder);
        $thread->start();
    }

    public function getThreadMessage($code,$msg)
    {
        echo "CODE:".$code ." MSG:".$msg;
    }
}


class TestThread extends Thread
{
    private $folder;

    /**
     * @var Test
     */
    private $test;

    private $filename = "test.txt";
    private $txt = "THIS IS A TEST";

    public function __construct(Test $test,$folder)
    {
        $this->test = $test;
        $this->folder = $folder;
    }

    public function run()
    {
        $resource = fopen($this->folder."/".$this->filename, 'w');
        if(!$resource)
        {
            $this->test->getThreadMessage(1001, "file open failed");
        }
        else
        {
            $writeBytes = fwrite($resource, $this->txt);
            $closed = fclose($resource);
            if(!$closed)
            {
                $this->test->getThreadMessage(1002, "file close failed");
            }
            else
            {
                $this->test->getThreadMessage(1002
                , "file write successfully ".$writeBytes."bytes ");
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```